# How to change Legend labels in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, legend, layouts

I am preparing layout in ArcGIS 10. I have duplicated data frame to have 2 images of the same area on single page. When I enter the legend, labels are in too small digits (24). I want it to bigger than this. Even I set the digits to 24 to 36 (make it bigger) in properties. It is still the same, unreadable. So how can I make it bigger? what is the problem with it?

Comment: Arc you *really* using ArcGIS 10.0, which was retired from support more than two years ago? Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact ArcGIS release, and clarify if you are asking abot digits or font size.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the legend and your current legend settings so that we can see the issue.